# What's an easy way of verifying whether or not two complicated expressions are equal

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let:
$$v=\frac{1}{1+i}$$

I would like to prove or disprove the following statement:
$$1+\frac{1}{p}v^\frac{1}{p}\frac{1-v^{n-1}}{1-v^{\frac{1}{p}}}=(1+i)^{\frac{1}{p}}\frac{1}{p}v^\frac{1}{p}\frac{1-v^{n}}{1-v^{\frac{1}{p}}}$$

What's an easy way to go about this without having to go through lengthy calculations?

Edit: Note that in the above notation, we do **not** have $i=\sqrt{-1}$

Comment: I would say the answer depends on the definition of "lengthy". I prefer the straigth forward way (here: plugging in $v$) whenever I have no clue of any known results that could provide an elegant solution. Straight forward has the advantage that it will lead to something to work with. -- Hint: Maybe you do not need to plug in everywhere? Terms that are equal left and right can remain dependent on $v$...

Comment: @mol3574710n0fN074710n I suppose what I meant by "lengthy" is the possibility (and the problem I am having) of substituting $v$ in, and then failing to manipulate both sides so that they are equal. If the above statement is in fact false, I could be here all day trying to prove it via substitution

Comment: Just try to substitute $v^-1$ for the $1+i$ in the leftmost bracket right side and try if you can isolate the expression on the left side from that. If a reminder appears you know it is wrong.

Comment: Also, you can try for some $i$, $i=0$ would be easiest.

Comment: @mol3574710n0fN074710n , I thought $i$ here was $\sqrt{-1}$?

Comment: Oh, lol, ok... That makes a *lot* sense actually.

Comment: Sorry guys. A bit misleading, but here I didn't mean for $i=\sqrt{-1}$. Actually, $i$ is an interest rate

Comment: @YinWaiTse Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$(1+i)^{\frac{1}{p}}=\frac1{v^{\frac{1}{p}}}$$

then

$$1+\frac{1}{p}v^\frac{1}{p}\frac{1-v^{n-1}}{1-v^{\frac{1}{p}}}=(1+i)^{\frac{1}{p}}\frac{1}{p}v^\frac{1}{p}\frac{1-v^{n}}{1-v^{\frac{1}{p}}}=\frac{1}{p}\frac{1-v^{n}}{1-v^{\frac{1}{p}}}$$

and multipling LHS and RHS by $p(1-v^{\frac{1}{p}})$

$$\iff p(1-v^{\frac{1}{p}})+v^\frac{1}{p}(1-v^{n-1})=1-v^{n}$$

$$\iff p +(1-p)v^{\frac{1}{p}}+v^{n-1+\frac{1}{p}}=1-v^{n}$$

which is not true in general indeed

- for $p=1$ and $\forall n$

$$1-v^{n}=1-v^{n}$$

- for $p=2$ and $n\neq \frac12$

$$2-\sqrt v+v^{n-\frac12}\neq1-v^{n}$$

Comment: Sorry!!! A bit misleading, but here I didn't mean for $i=\sqrt{-1}$. Actually, $i$ is an interest rate. So, your calculations no longer hold in this case

Comment: @YinWaiTse Why doesn't it hold? I haven't used that.

Answer (score 0):

Consider$$\text{lhs}=1+\frac{1}{p}v^\frac{1}{p}\frac{1-v^{n-1}}{1-v^{\frac{1}{p}}}=1+\frac{\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{i+1}\right)^{n-1}\right)
   \left(\frac{1}{i+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}}{p
   \left(1-\left(\frac{1}{i+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\right)}$$
$$\text{rhs}=(1+i)^{\frac{1}{p}}\frac{1}{p}v^\frac{1}{p}\frac{1-v^{n}}{1-v^{\frac{1}{p}}}=\frac{1-\left(\frac{1}{i+1}\right)^n
    }{p
   \left(1-\left(\frac{1}{i+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\right)}$$ They are equal if $i=0$.

Now, use Taylor series built at $i=0$ using the fact that
$$\frac 1{(1+i)^k}=1- k i+\frac{k (k+1)}{2}  i^2-\frac{k (k+1) (k+2)}{6} i^3 +O\left(i^4\right)$$ Just try with the first term and get 
$$\text{lhs}=n+\frac{ \left(-n^2 p+2 n p-n-p+1\right)}{2 p}i+O\left(i^2\right)$$
$$\text{rhs}=n+\frac{ \left(n-n^2 p\right)}{2 p}i+O\left(i^2\right)$$

They are not equal.